# Is the module `Regexp::Autoflags` deprecated?

Tags: perl

Is the module `Regexp::Autoflags` deprecated?

I cannot find it at cpan.

Comment: [`use re '/msxx';`](http://p3rl.org/re#'/flags'-mode) exists in core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you probably want [Regexp::DefaultFlags](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::DefaultFlags) (which was [apparently renamed](https://metacpan.org/source/AUTRIJUS/Regexp-DefaultFlags-0.01/Changes) from Regexp::Auto).

But it's rather old and looks unmaintained.

I guess you're following advice from *Perl Best Practices*. Not everything in that book should be taken as a hard and fast rule :-)